# Disable custom view in Excel

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007

I am using a shared excel workbook that everytime a user accesses it and saves it, it
saves a Custom View for them. I want to disable this settings so that every one can see only same view of the workbook. How it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable `Custom Views` in Excel (not that I can find anyway), but you can control how it works within a shared workbook. I ran into a problem where a share workbook was not the same for each person who printed it. I used the following to article to help me resolve the issue.

You weren't specific about any problems, so I am not positive this will do what you want.

[The page setup settings in a shared workbook are different for each user in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302911)

Answer (score 0):

I created a macro for this same situation that removes all the custom views on open and then removes extra users that are not using the sheet to prevent corruption and file bloat. The code for the macro is at the link below.

[How do you prevent corruption of shared Excel files?](https://superuser.com/questions/961918/how-do-you-prevent-corruption-of-shared-excel-files)